# use php functions as function argument

Tags: php, function, argument-passing

Can we call php function in custom function argument.

**Example**

```
function customFunction(trim($args),addslashes($args_second))
{
    //other code
}
```

That gave `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE` error. Is this correct way.?

I know i can do it inside function but why i can not do this way.?

Comment: Simply because the function definition rules don't permit this, that's the way the rules of the PHP Language syntax were defined

Comment: why are not using trim and addslashes function inside the function??

Comment: Because it's not in the language specification? And mostly because the parser will have hard time creating the symbolic table's entry for this function.

Comment: Even semantically this makes little sense. Does this mean the function expects argument one to be of type `trim()`? Does it mean the argument needs to be `trim`med? How do you reference the argument inside the function, since it's the result of `trim()`, which is assigned to nothing?

Comment: I must say, I don't know of any langauge that supports this. It could have quite some side effects.

Comment: @deceze, you could define semantics for it, and it would actually give extra info for the developer if she wants to call this function. It could be an interesting programming language feature.

Comment: @Bart If this was about something like type hinting, maybe that this syntax means that `$args` must be of a type compatible with `trim()`, I can see that. The OP wants it to mean "preprocess my arguments before they hit the function body" though, which to me sounds like a terrible idea. Do you want to support arbitrary expressions in the *function signature*, essentially allowing you to stuff the whole function body into the signature? As if PHP wasn't already prone enough to spaghetti code... :)

Comment: When that function can apply those functions to your arguments `inside` its body then why put those there, what difference would it make even if you find such a feature

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is impossible with php.

> Information may be passed to functions via the argument list, which is a comma-delimited list of expressions. The arguments are evaluated from left to right.
>
> PHP supports passing arguments by value (the default), [passing by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference), and [default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). [Variable-length argument lists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) are also supported.

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use expressions in the definition of function arguments. Only the assigment operator to specify a default value.

It's not possible because the arguments are not "evaluated".

Comment: I think the OP has already realised that, the question was *Why* it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is how the language is designed. You will have to put these calls inside your function definition:

```
function customFunction($args,$args_second)
{
    $args = trim($args);
    $args_second = addslashes($args_second);

    //other code
}
```

Comment: I didn't know PHP was "designed", xD.

Answer (score 0):

right way:

```
function customFunction($arg1,$arg2) {
 $arg1 = trim($arg1);
 $arg2 = addslashed($arg2);
 //do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, You can't do it in php.

you can do like this.

```
 function customFunction($arg1, $arg2) {
    $arg1 = trim($arg1);
    $arg2 = addslashes($arg2);
    // use $arg1 and $arg2
  }
```